# Connecting to remote TFS 2010 instance gives TF30063 error

Tags: iis, tfs, iis-6

I connect to a remote TFS 2010 instance using Visual Studio 2010.  I can Get Latest for all files within a particular project except for one database backup file.  When I try to Get Latest on this file I get the following error:

TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/6.0

I've tried clearing my local VS client cache, but that doesn't help.  There are no entries in the Event Logs to give any clues as to what is going on.

Any help appreciated, or any ideas where I can find out more diagnostic information via would be appreciated.

Colin.

**Update : Trace information shows the following, no real pointers**

```
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 5216, 115007 ms) Completed download: id = 0 in 61866          ms, active = 1
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 5216, 115007 ms) Web method response: [xxxxx.homeserver.com] Ver-Download: Napier.bak 61866 ms
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 5216, 115007 ms) Recorded m_exception in UpDownAsyncResult.Completed(): Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/6.0. at      Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.FileUploader.HandleErrorResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 5216, 115008 ms) Caught and converted to non-fatal error: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/6.0. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.EndDownloadFile(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Stream& downloadStream)  at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.AsyncGetFileState.Completed(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 5216, 115008 ms) Converted to non-fatal: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlException: C:\code\Remote\Napier\Trunk\Database Backups\Napier.bak: TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/6.0. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not   authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/6.0. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.EndDownloadFile(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Stream& downloadStream) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.AsyncGetFileState.Completed(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 2784, 115193 ms) DownloadFiles: 62061 ms
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 2784, 115193 ms) Acknowledgements: 0 ms
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 2784, 115349 ms) CreateWebRequest() -- Uri: https://xxxxxx.homeserver.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 2784, 115355 ms) request.AutomaticDecompression: GZip
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 2784, 115355 ms) Web method running: [https://xxxxxx.homeserver.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx] QueryItemsExtended[VersionControl]
06/01/2011 15:45:09 (pid 5560, tid 2784, 115649 ms) HTTP headers:
Content-Length: 1247
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2011 14:43:27 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Via: 1.1 Clearswift SECURE Web Gateway
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: Can you try enable tracing and see if there's any other information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2007/03/30/tfs-client-tracing.aspx?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the tracing setting.  I've updated the question to include the results

Comment: Instead of getting latest, can you do any other action on this file, such as checking history, check out for edit, etc.? I guess not but I'm just wondering.

Comment: I can view history, checking out is ghosted on the menu as you'd expect. I think this may be related to the size of the database file as it is 25Mb and I've been able to use it normally until today - it would have increased in size last night when I was working on it.  Am going to reduce it tonight to see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've fixed it.  I took the size of the database backup file down to 1.5Mb by removing obsolete data sets from it and it worked.

Not sure if it was a TFS problem or a work proxy problem - maybe a 25Mb file transfer limit imposed.  The latter seems more likely to me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a corrupt cache file on the server. I recommend logging on to the server and wiping the cache (usually under C:\program files\microsoft team foundation server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data\{guid}\proxy)

Delete all the files there (it's not going to break anything, that folder is just a cache) and try your Get Latest again (no need to restart the server). If that doesn't work, I recommend contacting MS Customer Support.

Comment: This one actually resolved the problem for us. Thanks!